# XML layout cannot be reconstructed programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

So at first I made an XML document and designed my layout there. It works perfectly and here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout style="@style/Row">
                <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                    <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                               android:id="@+id/imageView42" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                    <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                               android:id="@+id/imageView423" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout style="@style/Row">
                <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                    <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                               android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                    <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                               android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And there are styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Row">
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EntryContainer">
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Pic">
        <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Rate">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/underpic_rate</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Ok but I need to add these rows on runtime so at first I tried making new Views and passing concrete styles to its constructors (3rd parameter). It just didn't work. It looked like it hadn't added any style at all.

Then I tried using LayoutParams and it almost worked, but I can't change orientation of my LinearLayouts. When I do something like:

```
myLinearLayoutObject.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

It just doesn't listen to me.

I can post more of my code but I'm not sure if it's needed. **Basically I don't know why passing style to View's constructor doesn't work.** It would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Two things.  It is impossible to create a layout in XML that cannot be created in code and,  Just look at the source for layout inflater to see why.`Then I tried using LayoutParams and it almost worked` - what does "almost worked" mean?

Comment: It means that everything seemed to work except that thing I mentioned after that sentence you quoted.

Comment: Then please show the entire method.  You are doing something else wrong.  I've done lots of it and it does work.

Comment: You mean using LayoutParams? Is using styles impossible? I will try to provide it soon.

Comment: You cannot set orientation with layoutparams, and yes, using styles works fine.  All that the inflater does is call the constructors and set the layout params then build the view heirarchy.  You are just choosing to do it in code instead of using the lnflater.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to make this work with styles I provided? I think that this is the simpliest solution to my problem. What I tried and didn't work was:    View view = new View(context, null, R.style.style_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LayoutInflater.

Create another xml layout file representing the row - firstrow.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          style="@style/Row">
            <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                           android:id="@+id/imageView42" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout style="@style/EntryContainer">
                <ImageView style="@style/Pic"
                           android:id="@+id/imageView423" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                <TextView style="@style/Rate"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout rootView=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstrow, null);
final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list);
container.addView(rootView);
```

Comment: OK but can I do it multiple times on the same layout and operate as it was completely separated? I mean, for example: there are ids set. And what If i want to have only one Pic in Row and add another one later?

Comment: Yes as long as you are on the UI thread you can append as many row as you want. And if you want to later add another pic just get the LinearLayout that you need by id (I assume you will get the one with the EntryContainer style) and call .addView( your ImageView )...

Comment: You mean ID in layout xml file or? Because if there is id set in xml, then there should be one ID for many instances am I right? Also you said that I should .addView(my ImageView) but this ImageView needs to have "Pic" style applied. How to do this? Another layout? Can I do separate layout for every style and just add it to single views?

Comment: Yeah you're right about the ID; I was just making an example cause for calling findViewById you should provide a view ID...  Anyway in your case you can save the views to which you later want to append the image views   in an ArrayList and append the ImageViews when you need to using the same procedure of the LayoutInflater so that you have your style...

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Meanwhile I found a bug in my code which made it harder to find out what is wrong, but eventually I used your method. Still I have no idea why passing style in view's constructor does not work though.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead. This will allow you to have a list of similar view elements generated automatically based on the underlying data set.

If you have a dynamic set of list elements that will change throughout the runtime of your app, this will provide a much more flexible and elegant solution than manually creating a list with views yourself

It will take a bit more time to learn, but it will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am new to Android and I haven't got familiar with even basic views yet. What I need is everything that I provided in those 2 xml files. It won't change much. I will only change source of ImageView and content of TextView. And I also need to set onClickListener to ImageView. Also I need to be able to dynamically create new "Rows" with 2 "Pic" and 2 "Rate" inside (just like in example from the first .xml file I provided). That should be all.

Comment: Based on what you have written so far, I am not convinced that a RecyclerView is really what you need, But you can read up on it here (with examples) and determine if it will be best for your app. https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html On the other hand, it may be more appropriate to go more along the lines of Marco Dufal's answer. Once your full layout is inflated, find the views that will need to change with `findViewById()` and reference to them in a member variable of your fragment. Then when you need to change their values you can use the member variable.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is solved now. By the way it would be great if you could explain me why passing style in view's constructor does not work.